# unity navmeshsurface prefab not found or whatever

Tags: debugging

error CS1061: 'NavMeshSurface' does not contain a definition for 'IsPartOfPrefab' and no accessible extension method 'IsPartOfPrefab' accepting a first argument of type 'NavMeshSurface' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I dont know what to try or do